# React native exception thrown while executing UI block: -[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript : ]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2838507e0

Tags: react-native

I'm currently new to react native, and I'm stuck solving this exception error.
All i have done is importing the react-native-wheel-fortune library https://github.com/eftalyurtseven/react-native-wheel-of-fortune [here is the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBgs8.jpg).

Versions:
react-native: 0.71.8,
npm version : 9.6.4,